# High Performance

Tags: java, sql

I have a requirement to refer to a set of columns in a DB and update these columns. Since this set of columns is common/ shared across multiple parallel transactions, how do I achieve a good performance without compromising on data integrity and consistency. To provide more clarity, I have a long transaction, wherein, I do some pre-processing and compute certain values. I then compare this value against the limit. The limit is the common/ shared column, which I have to update, if I am proceeding further with the transaction. The application will have multiple users, who will try to perform a similar operation and have to compare against the same 'Limit' and proceed further.

Comment: What is `Limit` - some sort of index? Could you use a hilo optimiser?

Comment: May be more suitable for programmers....

Comment: Most databases do not support parallel transactions to the same tables.  I suggest you reconsider your design if you need transactions to work concurrently.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, the limit works like a sort of semaphore. Accessing the semaphore should not be part of the normal transaction. You want to increase the limit immediately, and if you fail you would like to abort the transaction.

A way of acheiving this is to run the limit increase as a sub-transaction. If you are using transaction demarcation you can use [TransactionAttributeType.html#REQUIRES_NEW](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html#REQUIRES_NEW).

If you want a more detailed answer, please clarify you question somewhat.